# PyLance not working in VS Code on Arch Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, archlinux, pylance

After installing the Python extension for VS Code, PyLance doesn't automatically install. After changing `python.languageServer` to PyLance, VS code now prompts me with the following.

[image]

After clicking Install Pylance, it seems like nothing happens. Here are the logs (after setting log level to Trace)

```
2023-01-17 22:49:18.392 [trace] CommandService#executeCommand extension.open
2023-01-17 22:49:18.397 [trace] RequestService#request (browser) - begin https://open-vsx.org/vscode/gallery/extensionquery
2023-01-17 22:49:18.565 [trace] RequestService#request (browser) - success https://open-vsx.org/vscode/gallery/extensionquery
2023-01-17 22:49:18.568 [trace] CommandService#executeCommand _extensions.manage
```

System info

```
 OS: Arch Linux 
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.15.11-arch2-1
 Uptime: 108d 12h 38m
 Packages: 1993
 Shell: bash 5.1.16
 Resolution: 3840x1080
 DE: KDE 5.102.0 / Plasma 5.26.5
 WM: KWin
 GTK Theme: Breeze [GTK3]
 Icon Theme: breeze-dark
 Disk: 157G / 267G (62%)
 CPU: Intel Core i7-6600U @ 4x 3.4GHz [50.0°C]
 GPU: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
 RAM: 8494MiB / 23909MiB
```

VS code version 1.74.3